# Can't delete nested libraries file

Tags: arduino

So, the thing is - I installed Arduino some time ago, and all of a sudden it stopped working. 
I did som ressearch, but found no answers, until some days ago when I stumbled upon something frustrating. Arduino had created 25 folders inside of eachother, called libraries. So, the filepath for my Arduino libraries is really long. Which results in me not being able to delete it, because of the filepath. I tried using cmd, i tried using unlocker, i tried using anti virus. I need Arduino for the course I'm studying, but i can't get it to work aslong as the libraries folder is screwed. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue just recently.  No idea why it's happening, but here's how I at least managed to delete all of the directories.

(The pain in the butt part of this is that you can't effectively delete files over 260 characters in windows.)

1. Start>Run>cmd.exe
2. Switch directories to the folder containing the first "libraries" folder.
3. "mkdir empty" to create an empty folder called "empty".
4. "robocopy empty libraries /mir"  this will mirror the empty directory to the libraries directory, overwriting everything in it with..well..nothing. :)
5. This will take some time, so just wait until it finishes.  It runs faster if you minimize the cmd window since it doesn't have to refresh the information on every new item.
6. Once it's done, "rd libraries" to remove the newly emptied libraries folder
7. "rd empty" to remove the empty folder.

That should start you off fresh :)

Cheers,
Patrick